# Plot PrincipalComponent2 and PrincipalComponent3 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, pca

I'm performing a Principal Component Analysis (PCA) using R. I'm using the `FactoMineR::PCA` function to perform the PCA and `factoextra::fviz_pca_var` function to draw the correlation plot and the contribution of each variable.

Here an example using the `decathlon2` dataset:

```
library(FactoMineR)
library(factoextra)

# Load data
decathlon2.active <- decathlon2[1:23, 1:10]
head(decathlon2.active[, 1:6], 4)

# Perform PCA
res.pca <- PCA(decathlon2.active, graph = FALSE)
print(res.pca)
```

Finally I draw the plot of correlations and the contribution of each variable.

```
# Plot of correlations
fviz_pca_var(res.pca, col.var = "contrib",
             gradient.cols = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"))
```

[image]

However, I am interested in generating a biplot with PC2 (X axis) vs PC3 (Y axis). How can I do this? Other PCA implementations such as `prcomp` are also useful for me.

Comment: try ```fviz_pca_biplot(res.pca, axes=2:3,col.var = "contrib", gradient.cols = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"))```

Comment: `fviz_pca_biplot(res.pca, axes=c(2,3),col.var = "contrib", gradient.cols = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"))` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the friendly user package GABB, possessing lots of graphic and intuitive options such as dim.a and dim.b. See below with basic and minimal parameters :

```
library(GABB)

PCA_RDA_graphics(PCA.object = res.pca, complete.data.set = decathlon2.active, 
                 factor.names = "X100m", Biplot.PCA = TRUE, Dim.a = 2, Dim.b = 3)
```

[image]